# How to push items to popup in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, arraylist, sass

I have the following data array:

```
public tools: Tool[] = [
    { image: './assets/img/OpenFolder.svg', title: 'Upload' },
    { image: './assets/img/Save.png', title: 'Save' },
    { image: './assets/img/Printer.png', title: 'Printing' },
    { image: './assets/img/Delete.png', title: 'Delete' },
    { image: './assets/img/Paste.svg', title: 'Paste' },
    { image: './assets/img/Copy.png', title: 'Copy' },
    { image: './assets/img/favicon.png', title: 'Rotate left' },
    { image: './assets/img/favicon.png', title: 'Rotate right' },
    { image: './assets/img/favicon.png', title: 'Flip vertical' },
    { image: './assets/img/favicon.png', title: 'Flip horizontal' },
    { image: './assets/img/favicon.png', title: 'Crop picture' },
    { image: './assets/img/favicon.png', title: 'Resize picture' },
    { image: './assets/img/favicon.png', title: 'Brightness' },
    { image: './assets/img/favicon.png', title: 'Color' },
    { image: './assets/img/favicon.png', title: 'Opacity' },
];
```

The HTML code:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let tool of tools" title="{{ tool.title }}"><img src="{{ tool.image }}"></li>
</ul>
```

And SCSS code:

```
ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

> Items display horizontally and inline when the screen is shrunk smaller than `max-width`

I'm hoping that when the screen shrinks to less than `max-width`, the newline items will be pushed into a pop-up window (only when the button is clicked will the window pop up)

*Looking forward to hearing from everyone!*

Comment: You should try to implement the logic you just mentioned yourself, and only come back when you run into a specific problem or error, ideally with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Currently it looks like you want others to code the mentioned popup logic for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use BreakpointObserver @angular/cdk/layout to observe the viewport-width in your component.

```
import {BreakpointObserver, BreakpointState} from '@angular/cdk/layout';
```

may look  something like this:

```
this.breakpointObserver
  .observe(['(max-width: 1024px)'])
  .subscribe((state: BreakpointState) => {
    // TODO: your logic
  });
```

Otherwise you just render your list twice in your markup and use mediaqueries in your css to switch visibility.